# Use Dynamic DNS With MacBook

Tags: mac, dns

I set up File Sharing on my MacBook in System Preferences > Sharing and I can now connect to my Mac and access its files from my iPhone, iPad and Windows PC **on my local network**. That's great, but I do also own a domain. I'm wondering if it's possible to use the Dynamic DNS feature in Google Domains to connect to my Mac so I can access its files from **anywhere**. Is this possible?

Comment: SMB (the MS Windows file sharing protocol) is now the preferred file sharing protocol for macOS, but it's also one of the top-two most-attacked protocols on the Internet, so opening up your home network to SMB requests from the Internet is generally considered a bad idea, even though most of the known exploitable flaws in the better-known SMB implementations (Windows and SaMBa) don't apply to Apple's implementation. But yes, there are Dynamic DNS clients for macOS, and you can set up port forwarding on your router to let SMB requests get through to your Mac.

Comment: @Spiff I second that. It would be much better security wise to setup a VPN server on your network.

Comment: How easy is it to do that @mashuptwice?

Comment: @RyderCragie wireguard is pretty easy on linux. I don't know about macOS, but the process should remain similar. Note that you would still need to set up a dynamic DNS as well as open one port on your router. Google has instructions on how to set up dynamic DNS with one of their domains: https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6147083?hl=en#zippy=%2Cset-up-a-client-program-on-your-gateway-host-or-server

Comment: Is it impossible to do it without opening ports?

Comment: Without opening the needed ports, access is blocked from the internet. I wouldn't counsel using Google Dynamic DNS but that of a third party.

Comment: "Without opening the needed ports, access is blocked from the internet." This answered my question. Looks like I won't be doing it then. Thank you.

Comment: I'd mark your reply as the answer if I could, but there's no tick.

*******RESOLVED*********

Comment: @RyderCragie: I wrote a fuller answer.

Answer (score 1):

All the credit to `@harrymc`, `mashuptwice` and `Spiff`

#### Short form

So you defnitely need a port forwarding to achieve this. The problem is that even though if your router supports DynDNS it won't know where to send the packages to.

#### What is DNS/DynDNS

DNS is a system where Domain names eg. google.com, test.google.com can be resolved into IP Addresses. This makes it easier for the end-consumer to reach a certain server, because he only has to remember a certain name or even brand and not an ip address which consits of numbers or even worse hexadecimal characters.

But there is one problem associated with DNS. Your personal ip address changes. In a worst case scenario multiple times a day (very uncommon). After each change you have to update your dns entry.

DynDNS solves this problem by offering a service which a client can connect to. The client (your machine) knows your ip and updates the entry for you.

#### What has that to do with your problem

But as you probably have noticed: This has noting to do with SMB. And that's the problem. SMB requires to have packets forwarded from your NAT to your machine, but your NAT (Router) doesn't know that you want to receive those requests. And therefore you need to tell your NAT exactly that. You do this by setting up a portforwarding.

Every packet which is addressed to your public IP Address and a specified port will be sent to the specified local IP Address.

I hope that helps. For improvements just comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Without opening the needed ports, access is blocked from the internet.

The required ports are listed in the Microsoft article
[Direct host SMB over TCP/IP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/direct-hosting-of-smb-over-tcpip):
Port 445 (TCP) is is the only SMB port needed, on condition that NETBIOS
is disabled (as it should be in your case).

I wouldn't counsel using Google Dynamic DNS but that of a third party.

I had good results with the free
[Dynu](https://www.dynu.com/Resources/Tutorials/DynamicDNS/RemoteDesktopMac)
service.
This link explains all the required steps for your Mac,
from registering a free Dynu account,
setting up Port Forwarding in the router,
up to mapping your dynamic IP to a hostname.
It uses VNC Viewer as an example, but that part is not needed
in your case (unless you would like it as a bonus).

Note that any port you open to the internet can be used as an
attack vector on your computer from the internet.
Setting up a VPN server on your computer can make it safer,
but more complex to set up.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have DynDNS or similar feature on your broadband router. If you have a public IP you can configure the router to pass the file sharing port to your Mac.

If you do not have a public IP or can't access to the router, then I suggest you get one of those 1$ /month VPS with a public IP, then you can create a reverse SSH tunnel to it from the mac.

Here's an example ssh command to create a tunnel that will send all traffic from port 21 on your VPS to port 21 on your mac:

> ssh -R 21:localhost:21 your-vps-server

Since the VPS IP is static you can just create an A or AAAA record that points to it:

> ftp 3600 IN A your-vps-server-ip

Then you can access the file server on your mac via ftp.yourdomain.com